# How to map values in place?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': list('aba'), 'c2': list('aaa'), 'ignore_me': list('bbb'), 'c3': list('baa')})

  c1 c2 ignore_me c3
0  a  a         b  b
1  b  a         b  a
2  a  a         b  a
```

and a dictionary that looks like this

```
d = {'a': "foo", 'b': 'bar'}
```

I now want to `map` the values of `d` to columns that match the `regex` `^c\d+$`.

I can do

```
df.filter(regex='^c\d+$').apply(lambda x: x.map(d))

    c1   c2   c3
0  foo  foo  bar
1  bar  foo  foo
2  foo  foo  foo
```

however, then the there are all the columns missing that don't match the regex.

So, I can therefore do:

```
tempdf = df.filter(regex='^c\d+$')

df.loc[:, tempdf.columns] = tempdf.apply(lambda x: x.map(d))
```

which gives the desired output

```
    c1   c2 ignore_me   c3
0  foo  foo         b  bar
1  bar  foo         b  foo
2  foo  foo         b  foo
```

Is there a smarter solution that avoids the tempory dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There absolutely is, use `str.contains`.

```
df.columns.str.contains(r'^c\d+$') # use raw strings, it's good hygene
# array([ True,  True, False,  True])
```

Pass the mask to `loc`:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains(r'^c\d+$')] = df.apply(lambda x: x.map(d))
```

If you want to be as efficient as possible,

```
m = df.columns.str.contains(r'^c\d+$')
df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m].apply(lambda x: x.map(d))
```

---

```
df

    c1   c2 ignore_me   c3
0  foo  foo  b         bar
1  bar  foo  b         foo
2  foo  foo  b         foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the smartest way, but I think is quite neat...:

```py
# Your code
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': list('aba'), 'c2': list('aaa'), 'ignore_me': list('bbb'), 'c3': list('baa')})
d = {'a': "foo", 'b': 'bar'}

# Solution
import re # cs95 provided a better solution to pick columns!

# Pre-compile the regex object in case there is a huge list of columns....
regex = re.compile(r'^c\d+$')

# Python 3's `filter` returns a `generator`, add a `list` wrapper to get the columns 
cols = list(filter(regex.search, df.columns))
# output ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']


# PICK one of the following...:

# The normal way
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.map(d))

# OR use `applymap`
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(lambda x: d[x])

# OR if you prefer not to see `lambda` at all!
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(d.get)

df
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace?

`df.filter(regex='^c\d+$').apply(lambda x: x.replace(d))`

You might also find [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) useful for this type of filtering problem.

Comment: That does not give a different output than I currently have.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. I thought the `map` operation was inserting `NaN`, not the `filter`.